# Python: alphabet count

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need someone to help me with the explaination for the below code.
After looking at the solution, it took me some time to figure out that the number actually represents the humber of times the alphabet being counted. However, am very weak in python.

So, could someone explain to me in plain English how the alphabet count is tied to the number list please?

```
line = 'abcdef'
count = [3,4,7,1,2,5]
index = 0
while index < len(line):
  print(count[index], end=' ')
  for k in range(0,count[index]):
    print(line[index],end='')
  print()
  index = index + 1
```

OUTPUT

```
3 aaa
4 bbbb
7 ccccccc
1 d
2 ee
5 fffff
```

Comment: When you're stuck with something like this, try running it in an interactive visualizer, like [this one](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=line+%3D+'abcdef'%0Acount+%3D+%5B3,4,7,1,2,5%5D%0Aindex+%3D+0%0Awhile+index+%3C+len(line)%3A%0A++print(count%5Bindex%5D,+end%3D'+')%0A++for+k+in+range(0,count%5Bindex%5D)%3A%0A++++print(line%5Bindex%5D,end%3D'')%0A++print()%0A++index+%3D+index+%2B+1&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=3&curInstr=0).

Comment: Thanks, it somehow useful. But as stated, programming is not my strength.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop generates an index between `0` and `len(line) - 1`, using that index both on `line` and `count`. As such, `count` is expected to be the same length.

To follow this through:

1. As long as `index` is smaller than `len(line)`, keep looping.
2. print `count[index]`, with a space after it, no newline.
3. loop from `0` to `count[index] - 1`. This'll loop `count[index]` times. In this `for` loop, print `line[index]` with no newline, resulting in the character being printed `count[index]` times.
4. Print a newline
5. Increment `index`.

The first iteration, `index` is `0`, which is smaller than `len(line)`. `line[0]` is `a`, `count[0]` is 3, so after printing `3`, `a` is printed 3 times.

The second iteration, `index` is `1`, which is smaller than `len(line)`. `line[1]` is `b`, `count[1]` is 4, so after printing `4`, `b` is printed 4 times.

etc. until `index` is `6`, at which point the `while` loop ends.

The code could be simplified to:

```
for char, c in zip(line, count):
    print(c, c * char)
```

Comment: for char, c in zip(line, count): ->zip function is?

print(c,c*char) -> I know * is multiplication, but what's exactly it's performing. Is it a character count?

Comment: @Macrick: multiplying a string with a number results in a repeated string. `'a' * 3` is `'aaa'`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets go through it one iteration at a time:

- 1st iteration: `index` is 0, `count[0]` is `3`, `line[0]` is `'a'`.  So we print `3`, and then print `'a'` 3 times
- 2nd iteration: `index` is 1, `count[1]` is `4`, `line[1]` is `'b'`.  So we print `4`, and then print `'b'` 4 times

Hopefully that is enough to make it clear what is happening.